# Why does Enumerable.Single() iterate all elements, even when more than one item has already been found?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

When profiling one of our applications, we discovered a mysterious slowdown in some code where we were calling `Enumerable.Single(source, predicate)` for a large collection that had more than one item that matched the predicate near the start of the collection.

Investigation revealed that [the implementation of `Enumerable.Single()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) is as follows:

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{
        TSource result = default(TSource);
        long count = 0;
        // Note how this always iterates through ALL the elements:
        foreach (TSource element in source) { 
            if (predicate(element)) {
                result = element;
                checked { count++; }
            }
        }
        switch (count) {
            case 0: throw Error.NoMatch();
            case 1: return result;
        }
        throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch();
    }
```

That implementation will iterate through every element of the sequence, even if more than one element has already matched the predicate.

The following implementation would appear to yield the same results:

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    TSource result = default(TSource);
    long count = 0;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            if (count == 1) // Exit loop immediately if more than one match found.
                throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch();

            result = element;
            count++; // "checked" is no longer needed.
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
        throw Error.NoMatch();

    return result;
}
```

Does anyone know why the actual implementation doesn't use this obvious optimization? Is there something I'm missing? (I can't imagine that such an obvious optimization would be overlooked, and therefore there must be some concrete reason for it.)

(Note: I realize that this question may attract answers that are opinions; I'm hoping for answers that provide concrete reasons for iterating all elements. If the answer is actually "because the designers didn't think such an optimization was necessary", then this question is unanswerable and I guess I should just delete it...)

---

For comparison, look at the implementation of `Single()` which does not take a predicate:

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
{
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        switch (list.Count) {
            case 0: throw Error.NoElements();
            case 1: return list[0];
        }
    }
    else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.NoElements();
            TSource result = e.Current;
            if (!e.MoveNext()) return result;
        }
    }
    throw Error.MoreThanOneElement();
}
```

In this case, they've gone to the effort of adding an optimisation for `IList`.

Comment: Optimizing failure paths is rarely worth doing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In that case, why did they optimise `SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` to cast the source to `IList` and check the count directly?

Comment: What happens if an exception is thrown when enumerating the sequence after the second match? Returning early would change the behaviour. Which is the desired result is questionable though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - the `IList` optimizations are only for the predicate-free versions of both of these methods - where knowing the length of the list immediately answers the question. With the predicate, for the success case, it has to evaluate the predicate against every item anyway.

Comment: See also https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions/ - this uses your early out.

Comment: I though that devs wanted to use `count` somewhere, but later they just decided to leave it as it was

Comment: Interesting - so performance is actually better for `Where` then `Single` (on the full .NET Framework) vs `Single` with predicate. Nice find @MatthewWatson.

Comment: Why not using `FirstOrDefault` ?

Comment: For some reason there is no easy to find duplciates from 2015/2016... We only have 2011 and 2013 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743231/why-does-single-not-return-directly-when-more-than-one-element-is-found. Someone need to decide which way to close - probably older dup to this one as it has newer answers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If you ask me, the original answer from 2011 is much better than current. It doesn't matter that current question and answer are highly upvoted. People tend to upvote anything which is said to be *others* (and especially MS) bug :) The whole effect of the "obvious optimization" is debatable - with or w/o optimizations, the algorithm is O(N) in most of the cases, and in general `Single[OrDefault]` is a strange method and should not be used. What really is it - search + validation - why? If I need unique things, I will request data structure that guarantee that (+ fast lookup)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You didn't seem to be the only one thinking that. The [.NET Core implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs#L48) has an optimized version:

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        TSource result = e.Current;
        if (predicate(result))
        {
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (predicate(e.Current))
                {
                    throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

So to answer your question: there doesn't seem to be a 'good' reason, other than just a developer not thinking about optimizing this use case.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not just “a developer not thinking about optimization”, it’s an (amortised) asymptotically less efficient implementation of a trivial algorithm. That’s a straightforward performance *bug* … and a pretty bad one, at that.

Comment: You can classify it as that, I agree. That is why the community put so much work in optimizing the performance of .NET Core. It are these small changes that make a huge performance impact @KonradRudolph

Comment: It looks like part of the program behavior is to throw an error if there is more than one match. It wouldn't be able to satisfy said behavior without iterating through the entire collection

Comment: @danielmhanover That is not true. The code checks "more than one". Two is more than one so you can stop when you have a second match.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, throwing exceptions is a clue that this branch should be avoided by the developer. So it's not a performance *bug*, if an exception is slower than it might potentially be. This might be a case of backwards compatibility.

Comment: @IMil It has nothing to do with backwards compatibility since the semantics are the same, only the performance characteristics change (drastically). And your understanding of the exception being thrown is also wrong: yes, that path should be avoided but ironically that’s the *fast* path. The slow path won’t throw an exception (but needs to inspect every element). To be fair, the *expected* performance is thus always O(n), it will only vary in the case of an exception.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, the behavior changes; if the predicate has side effects, the one that throws-on-two behaves very differently.

Comment: @Yakk C# is under-specified in this regard but it’s pretty much understood that user code must not rely on deterministic behaviour of side-effects in predicates and similar functions: The documentation does not define how (and even *whether*) predicates are called. So the *documented* behaviour doesn’t change.

Comment: @KonradRudolph there's such a thing as backwards bug compatibility: you'd like not to turn potentially buggy programs into really buggy with a framework update. Anyway, there was no promise that the operation would be faster in the exceptional case, so the OP's words about "mysterious slowdown" seem strange to me.

Comment: @IMil Take a step back, you seem confused. “Backwards [bug] compatibility” simply doesn’t come into play here at all: the code *was* changed, and the running time *was* changed. We’re discussing the old implementation here, not the impossibility of changing it (which would be moot, since it was changed).

Comment: @KonradRudolph bug compatibility doesn't apply here indeed. .NET Core is an entirely different product from .NET classic, so obviously any migration from .NET to .NET Core requires extensive testing. Meanwhile, if someone decided to "optimize" Single in an upgrade from, say, version 3.5 to 3.5.1, it is entirely possible that existing programs would change behaviour in unexpected ways.

Comment: @IMil Name a way, please

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry, but it was already named multiple times. Side effects of predicates. These might be quite subtle, like caching data in the object fields. Say, your predicate accesses property that is lazy-loaded from a file or DB. The current behaviour means these operations will take place when Single() is called. Once you optimize it, they will occur at some later time, when the data may have changed already, or the transaction was closed, or whatever.

Answer (score 10):

The optimization [was applied in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs#L11)

The code now is  :

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
    }

    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(predicate));
    }

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource result = e.Current;
            if (predicate(result))
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(e.Current))
                    {
                        throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch();
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    throw Error.NoMatch();
}
```

Wherever possible, the code even checks whether the target is an `IList<T>` so it can avoid iterating:

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
    }

    if (source is IList<TSource> list)
    {
        switch (list.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                throw Error.NoElements();
            case 1:
                return list[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext())
            {
                throw Error.NoElements();
            }

            TSource result = e.Current;
            if (!e.MoveNext())
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    throw Error.MoreThanOneElement();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Checking the [git blame](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blame/08534ae1cf989696a0f1aac4a30a24e907983119/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs#L18) output shows that the iteration optimization was applied back in 2016!

The `IList<>` optimization was added 1 year ago, probably as part of the Core 2.1 optimizations

Comment: Well this answers the question: It was actually a missed opportunity, which was corrected.

Comment: @MatthewWatson a lot of optimizations were added when 2.1 was introduced but *Single.cs* seems to go back to 2016

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have pointed out, the optimization has been applied, but I would just like to raise the hypothesis that they had done it that way originally thinking of the fact that they have no way to guarantee that the predicate function does not have side effects.

I'm not sure that there would truly be a case where such behavior would be used/useful, but it is a consideration to keep in mind.

Comment: Technically the question is "Why does it iterate over all the elements" The other answers all state oversight as the reason I was giving an alternative to the answer that didnt claim the designers were incompetent

Comment: I see your point @TurtleKwitty, my apologies for not seeing it the first time round. Thanks for the clarification. I've removed my review comment.

Comment: I don't think this answer makes a lot of sense because the same reasoning could be applied to other methods, for example `First()`, which has a well-optimized implementation.

Comment: @Kapol, not quite; First() litersally gets the first item in the set, while single does a search for it; First doesnt need to touch the variables or run any algorithms, it just gets the first one no questions asked